# Why is 'all(itr) do' block slower than a for loop in this case?

Tags: performance, julia, benchmarking

### What my code does

The goal was to build a function, that checks if all brackets open and close correctly in a given string with julia. So,

```
"{abc()([[def]])()}"
```

should return true, while something like

```
"{(bracket order mixed up here!})[and this bracket doesn't close!"
```

should return false.

### Question

I have two versions of the function. **Why is version I faster by about 10%?**

#### Version I

```
function matching_brackets_old(s::AbstractString)
    close_open_map = Dict('}' => '{', ')' => '(', ']' => '[')
    order_arr = []
    for char in s
        if char in values(close_open_map)
            push!(order_arr, char)
        elseif (char in keys(close_open_map)) &&
            (isempty(order_arr) || (close_open_map[char] != pop!(order_arr)))
            return false
        end
    end
    return isempty(order_arr)
end
```

#### Version II

Here I replace the for loop with a do block:

```
function matching_brackets(s::AbstractString)
    close_open_map = Dict('}' => '{', ')' => '(', ']' => '[')
    order_arr = []
    all_correct = all(s) do char
        if char in values(close_open_map)
            push!(order_arr, char)
        elseif (char in keys(close_open_map)) &&
            (isempty(order_arr) || (close_open_map[char] != pop!(order_arr)))
            return false
        end
        return true
    end
    return all_correct && isempty(order_arr)
end
```

#### Timings

Using BenchmarkTools' @benchmark for the strings `"{()()[()]()}"` and `"{()()[())]()}"`, I get a slow down up of about 10% for both strings, when comparing minimum execution time.

### Additional Info

Version Info:

```
Julia Version 1.3.1
Commit 2d5741174c (2019-12-30 21:36 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4260U CPU @ 1.40GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)
```

Timing Code:

```
using BenchmarkTools

benchmark_strings = ["{()()[()]()}", "{()()[())]()}"]
for s in benchmark_strings
    b_old = @benchmark matching_brackets_old("$s") samples=100000 seconds=30
    b_new = @benchmark matching_brackets("$s") samples=100000 seconds=30
    println("For String=", s)
    println(b_old)
    println(b_new)
    println(judge(minimum(b_new), minimum(b_old)))
    println("Result: ", matching_brackets(s))
end
```

With Result:

```
For String={()()[()]()}
Trial(8.177 μs)
Trial(9.197 μs)
TrialJudgement(+12.48% => regression)
Result: true
For String={()()[())]()}
Trial(8.197 μs)
Trial(9.202 μs)
TrialJudgement(+12.27% => regression)
Result: false
```

### Edit

I mixed up the order on the Trialjudgement, so Version I is faster, as François Févotte suggests. My question remains: why?

Comment: Since this is a working implementation, I suggest you also ask about this code on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for more feedback.

Comment: @phipsgabler: questions about nitty gritty details of *why* one version is faster are perfectly on-topic for SO (as long as it includes details about the test setup, including compiler version / options and hardware).  A CR question about this code might be one asking for feedback on whether it's efficient (and otherwise well-written), not trying to explain an existing performance difference.

Comment: @PeterCordes absolutely, I didn't mean to say it wasn't on topic. I just suggested it, as the code is working, and I, for one, would like to give more feedback, which in turn would not make a good answer on SO, but on CR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that the mistake with `judge` is resolved, the answer is probably the usual caveat: function calls, as in this case resulting from the closure passed to `all`, are quite optimized, but not for free.

To get a real improvement, I suggest, other than making the stack type stable (which isn't that big a deal here), to get rid of the iterations you implicitely do by calling `in` on `values` and `keys`.  It suffices to do that only once, without a dictionary:

```
const MATCHING_PAIRS = ('{' => '}', '(' => ')', '[' => ']')

function matching_brackets(s::AbstractString)
    stack = Vector{eltype(s)}()
    for c in s
        for (open, close) in MATCHING_PAIRS
            if c == open
                push!(stack, c)
            elseif c == close
                if isempty(stack) || (pop!(stack) != open)
                    return false
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return isempty(stack)
end
```

Even a bit more time can be squeezed out by unrolling the inner loop over the tuple:

```
function matching_brackets_unrolled(s::AbstractString)
    stack = Vector{eltype(s)}()
    for c in s
        if (c == '(') || (c == '[') || (c == '{')
            push!(stack, c)
        elseif (c == ')')
            if isempty(stack) || (pop!(stack) != '(')
                return false
            end
        elseif (c == ']')
            if isempty(stack) || (pop!(stack) != '[')
                return false
            end
        elseif (c == '}')
            if isempty(stack) || (pop!(stack) != '{')
                return false
            end
        end
    end
    return isempty(stack)
end
```

This is somewhat ugly and certainly not nicely extendable, though.  My benchmarks (`matching_brackets_new` is your second version, `matching_brackets` my first one):

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.3.1
Commit 2d5741174c (2019-12-30 21:36 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         960  @ 3.20GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, nehalem)


# NOT MATCHING
julia> @benchmark matching_brackets_new("{()()[())]()}")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  784 bytes
  allocs estimate:  16
  --------------
  minimum time:     674.844 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      736.200 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        800.935 ns (6.54% GC)
  maximum time:     23.831 μs (96.16% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     160

julia> @benchmark matching_brackets_old("{()()[())]()}")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  752 bytes
  allocs estimate:  15
  --------------
  minimum time:     630.743 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      681.725 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        753.937 ns (6.41% GC)
  maximum time:     23.056 μs (94.19% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     171

julia> @benchmark matching_brackets("{()()[())]()}")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  112 bytes
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     164.883 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      172.900 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        186.523 ns (4.33% GC)
  maximum time:     5.428 μs (96.54% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     759

julia> @benchmark matching_brackets_unrolled("{()()[())]()}")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  112 bytes
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     134.459 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      140.292 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        150.067 ns (5.84% GC)
  maximum time:     5.095 μs (96.56% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     878


# MATCHING 
julia> @benchmark matching_brackets_old("{()()[()]()}")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  800 bytes
  allocs estimate:  18
  --------------
  minimum time:     786.358 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      833.873 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        904.437 ns (5.43% GC)
  maximum time:     29.355 μs (96.88% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     106

julia> @benchmark matching_brackets_new("{()()[()]()}")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  832 bytes
  allocs estimate:  19
  --------------
  minimum time:     823.597 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      892.506 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        981.381 ns (5.98% GC)
  maximum time:     47.308 μs (97.84% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     77

julia> @benchmark matching_brackets("{()()[()]()}")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  112 bytes
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     206.062 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      214.481 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        227.385 ns (3.38% GC)
  maximum time:     6.890 μs (96.22% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     535

julia> @benchmark matching_brackets_unrolled("{()()[()]()}")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  112 bytes
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     160.186 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      164.752 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        180.794 ns (4.95% GC)
  maximum time:     5.751 μs (97.03% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     800
```

---

Update: if you insert `break`s in the first version, to *really* avoid unnecessary looping, the timings are almost indistinguishable, with nice code:

```
function matching_brackets(s::AbstractString)
    stack = Vector{eltype(s)}()
    for c in s
        for (open, close) in MATCHING_PAIRS
            if c == open
                push!(stack, c)
                break
            elseif c == close
                if isempty(stack) || (pop!(stack) != open)
                    return false
                end
                break
            end
        end
    end
    return isempty(stack)
end
```

with

```
julia> @benchmark matching_brackets_unrolled("{()()[())]()}")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  112 bytes
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     137.574 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      144.978 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        165.365 ns (10.44% GC)
  maximum time:     9.344 μs (98.02% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     867

julia> @benchmark matching_brackets("{()()[())]()}") # with breaks
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  112 bytes
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     148.255 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      155.231 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        175.245 ns (9.62% GC)
  maximum time:     9.602 μs (98.31% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     839
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one issue: I think you need to replace the `&&` with `||` and remove the not (`!`) in front of the isempty in the unrolled function.

Comment: Oh, indeed, that got lost during the rewrites.

Comment: @Luapulu see my update -- the nice version can be made practically as fast as the other one, if one does not forget to break out of the inner loop, as I did... :)

Comment: Ah, yes, I remembering wondering why you didn't break out. Thanks!

Comment: `for (close, open)` should be `for (open, close)`

Answer (score 2):

I don't observe the same on my machine: in my tests, version I is faster for both strings:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.3.0
Commit 46ce4d7933 (2019-11-26 06:09 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
Environment:
  JULIA_PROJECT = @.

julia> @btime matching_brackets_old("{()()[()]()}")
  716.443 ns (18 allocations: 800 bytes)
true

julia> @btime matching_brackets("{()()[()]()}")
  761.434 ns (19 allocations: 832 bytes)
true

julia> @btime matching_brackets_old("{()()[())]()}")
  574.847 ns (15 allocations: 752 bytes)
false

julia> @btime matching_brackets("{()()[())]()}")
  612.793 ns (16 allocations: 784 bytes)
false
```

I would think (but this is a wild guess) that the difference between for loops and higher-order functions gets less and less significant when the string size increases.

However, I would encourage you to look more closely at the `order_arr` variable: as it is currently written, it is of type `Vector{Any}`, which - like any container of abstractly typed values - hurts performance. The following version performs better by concretely typing the elements of `order_arr`:

```
function matching_brackets_new(s::AbstractString)
    close_open_map = Dict('}' => '{', ')' => '(', ']' => '[')

    # Make sure the compiler knows about the type of elements in order_arr
    order_arr = eltype(s)[]  # or order_arr = Char[]

    for char in s
        if char in values(close_open_map)
            push!(order_arr, char)
        elseif (char in keys(close_open_map)) &&
            (isempty(order_arr) || (close_open_map[char] != pop!(order_arr)))
            return false
        end
    end
    return isempty(order_arr)
end
```

yielding:

```
julia> @btime matching_brackets_new("{()()[()]()}")
  570.641 ns (18 allocations: 784 bytes)
true

julia> @btime matching_brackets_new("{()()[())]()}")
  447.758 ns (15 allocations: 736 bytes)
false
```

Comment: What kind of machine *do* you have?  Intel Skylake?  AMD Zen+?  A dorito? And what compiler version/options?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried declaring the type of the array with `Char[]`, but it makes no difference for those two strings. I'll try in a sec for a much longer string.

Comment: Jup, makes a big difference for larger strings.